# strip p tags if it's surrounding an image link?

Tags: jquery

The platform I'm building a website on adds `p` tags around image links in wysiwyg mode and this messes up the layout. Is there anyway I can use jQuery to strip the `p` tags if it's surrounding an image?

```
<div class="post">
    <p><a href="link"><img src="image"></a></p>
    <p><a href="link"><img src="image"></a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('p > a > img').parent().unwrap();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6z4Sv/

If there's some variation to the hierarchy inside the `p` elements, you can do this:

```
$('p img').closest('p > *').unwrap();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6z4Sv/1/

And you can use `div.post` at the beginning of the selector if you only want to affect `p` elements that descend from that class.

You can make the selector more or less specific as need be.

Comment: @Amadan: True. Hard to say if the selector needs to be more or less specific in the actual implementation.